# R Displaying Points Twice?

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, geospatial

I have this code for an interactive map in R:

```
library(leaflet)
library(inlmisc)

Long = rnorm(1000, -71, 0.5)
Lat = rnorm(1000, 42.3, 0.5)

loc = rep("loc", 1000)
Name = rep("Location", 1000)
num = 1:1000
Label = paste0(loc, "_", num)
Location = paste0(Name, "_", num)

df = data.frame(Name, Lat, Long, Label)

map <- leaflet(df) %>%   addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
    addMarkers( clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), popup = ~paste("title: ", Name)) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    setView(lng=-71.0589,lat=42.3301, zoom=12) %>%
    addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, popup = ~Name, group="marker", label = ~Label) %>% 
    inlmisc::AddSearchButton(group = "marker", zoom = 15,
                             textPlaceholder = "Search here")
```

The map seems to work fine - but the "icons" are being displayed twice (i.e. blue pins and colored circles, e.g. yellow, green):

[image]

Is there a way to have it such that when you zoom out, the blue pins collapse into the colorful circles - and when you zoom in, the colorful circles collapse into the blue pins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are adding the markers twice.

The first `addMarkers` line, does the clustering with zoom that it sound like you are interested in.

You can add the `group` and `label` options to the first `addMarkers` call, to be able to search and have mouse-over labels as well as the clustering.

```
map <- leaflet(df) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  addMarkers( clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), 
              popup = ~paste("title: ", Name),
              group="marker", label = ~Label) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng=-71.0589,lat=42.3301, zoom=12) %>%
  inlmisc::AddSearchButton(group = "marker", zoom = 15,
                           textPlaceholder = "Search here")
```

Comment: @ Senithil913 : You perfectly solved this question - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of @Senithil913 - I added a reset option:

```
map <- leaflet(df) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
    addMarkers( clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), 
                popup = ~paste("title: ", Name),
                group="marker", label = ~Label) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    setView(lng=-71.0589,lat=42.3301, zoom=12) %>%
    inlmisc::AddSearchButton(group = "marker", zoom = 15,
                             textPlaceholder = "Search here") %>%  addResetMapButton()
```